# From which country does php cURL access to page.. users or servers

Tags: php, curl, http-referer

I'm trying to access a page's content using PHP cURL with following function

```
$target_url = "http://www.amazon.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

As i asked in my question above "**From which country does php cURL access to page.. users or servers**"

If my webpage is on a server in Europe (where cURL script is running), And user is browsing from Pakistan. That webpage (cURL) function is calling page from website in USA...

Will the website in USA will get "browser's referrer from Pakistan or Europe"?

Suppose website is banned in Europe while accessible in Pakistan, will cURL will get banned response from USA's website or be visible because user is browsing it form Pakistan. ?

Comment: As you are running curl on the server, the request has to come from Europe.

Comment: The receiving end is going to look at the IP of the requester (your server in this case).

Comment: *All* PHP code runs on the server, before the page / response is sent to the client.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response..